# gnome-software corrupted

Tags: apt, 18.04, gnome, dpkg

Whenever I try to install a package, a part or the whole series of these error massages keep showing and I am unable to install any package.

```
    dpkg: error processing package gnome-software (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-software:
 ubuntu-software depends on gnome-software (>= 3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.8); however:
  Package gnome-software is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-software (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-software-plugin-snap:
 gnome-software-plugin-snap depends on gnome-software (= 3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.8); however:
  Package gnome-software is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-software-plugin-snap (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gnome-software
 ubuntu-software
 gnome-software-plugin-snap
```

Also adding any kind of repository results in issues with apt-secure.

Currently I am running LXDE environment on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  In the messages there are likely commands it suggests you try. For example `sudo apt -f install`.  I suspect you've added non-official sources to your system causing issues that will be visible higher up in report than where you pasted.

Comment: @guiverc I already tried sudo apt -f install, it didnt work.

Comment: Yep - but the clues needed are in the error report (of which you pasted only part for us to help you with).  My suggestion was to read the rest & take note of the clues provided there. The package names related to the actual cause are earlier, or in your logs. These I suspect (with `apt-cache policy` queries) will show a invalid/non-official source that has invalid (or clashing) package versions; but I can't see what you don't paste.  If you examine your logs, the command before your first error is your likely culprit.